# How to get props from a child view in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a react-native view like this.

```
<Parent>
 <Header/>
</Parent>
```

The header is also a view with some text input fields and icons. The Parent is another view created by adding the Header component. So what I want to do is, when I type some text on the text field which is located in the Header view, I want to take that value to the Parent view props. How to do this??? I've tried some answers that showed in StackOverflow. But they didn't give me what I expected.

For someone who wants to see the full code, This is the parent screen.

```
export default class ParentScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      objects: null,
      indicator: true,
    };
  }

render(){
 <View style={styles.container}>
       <HeaderBar />
    </View>
}}
```

And this is the Header screen.

```
export default class HeaderBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
    searchEnabled: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.navigationBar}>
        <View style={styles.titleArea}>
          {this.state.searchEnabled === true ? (
            <View style={styles.titleArea}>
              <Icon
                name="arrow-back"
                type="Ionicons"
                color="black"
                onPress={() => this.setState({ searchEnabled: false })}
              />
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Search"
                placeholderTextColor="white"
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ filterKey: text })}
              />
            </View>
          ) : (
            <View style={styles.titleArea}>
               <Image
                  style={styles.profileImage}
                  source={require("../../images/user_image_1.jpg")}
                />
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should pass a prop from the parent to the child. That prop is a callback that updates the parent state.

Comment: can you give me some example code or some related document? It would be really helpful.

Comment: Sure, I'll write a brief answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function in the parent View, something like:

```
  onChangeText = (text) => {
    this.setState({
      myUpdatedText: text
    })
  }
```

Then, pass it to the child as a prop:

```
  <HeaderBar onChangeText={this.onChangeText} />
```

So in the child code you can use it like:

```
  <TextInput
    placeholder="Search"
    placeholderTextColor="white"
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
  />
```

Comment: OK, I'll try it.

Comment: Let me know if there's something not clear enough or if I misunderstood your question

Comment: And one more thing. How can I use this as a function call in the child component? I mean I want to call a method when the text is entered and in that method pass the value to the parent?

Comment: That's currently what @Milore answer do. onChantText is calling the function onChangeText of the parent with all its parameters